# Яким чином прислівник "нагору" став "на-гора"?

Tags: словотворення, прислівники

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/na-ghora) читаю:

> **НА-ГОРА́,** присл., гірн. ***Нагору***, на поверхню землі. А вийдеш на-гора, — який красивий тутешній край (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954, 150).

Однак зацікавило, яким чином було утворено прислівник "на-гора"? Адже словотвір тут дещо нетиповий, як на мене.

Answer (score 2):

[Етимологічний словник Т. 4: Н — П / Уклад.: Р. В. Болдирєв та ін.; Ред. тому: В. Т. Коломієць, В. Г. Скляренко. — 2003. — 22 С.](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm)  має:

> **на-гора́** (гірн.) «нагору, на поверхню землі»;
>
> р. *на-гора́*, бр. *на-гара́*;
>
> очевидно, засвоєна в 19 сторіччі від іноземного технічного персоналу на шахтах Донбасу неправильна форма укр. *наго́ру*;
>
> пошуки джерела цього слова в російських діалектах (Отин РР 1969/6, 104—105) позбавлені підстав.
>
> Див. ще **гора́**, **на¹**.